# How does Tab Index work if the control's enabled property is false

Tags: vb.net

If I'm viewing a form and I set the enabled property of the control with tab index = 0, does the cursor then move to the next tab index? Do I need to, and is there a way, to force the tab to set to the first control with Enabled = True?

Comment: _"does the cursor then move to the next tab index?"_ The answer is yes. The focus always goes to the control with the next tab index and skips the disabled controls. Did you try it?

Comment: You want the control moved to the next control having the tab index greater than the current one, or just the first control from the tab index list with enabled = True?

Comment: @Gabriel Stanco - I'm looking for the second option, moving to the first enabled control.

Comment: Do you have nested controls? I mean, are all controls displayed directly on the form or you have panels (for instance) also? I will post an answer assuming no panels, which should be easy to modify to iterate through panels as well.

Comment: Simply TRY it yourself and find out. Place a few controls on the form, configure their properties, disable some of them and run the program.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to achieve this (assuming there are no panels on your form), this is how you could iterate through the controls in tab order. The first control which you encounter and which is enabled, you set the focus on it and leave the Sub. The `myFirstControl` variable is initialized by you with the first control in the tab order list of the form.

```
Private Sub IterateControls()
    Dim ctrl As Control = myFirstControl
    While ctrl IsNot Nothing
        If ctrl.Enabled = True Then
            Me.ActiveControl = ctrl
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    End While
End Sub
```

If you have panels also, you should build a dictionary of panels (with the panel as key, its first control as value) and take them one by one using a `For` loop. The `For` loop should be placed to include the whole method's code, but this time you initiate the `ctrl` variable with the first control from the panel (i.e. the value of the current dictionary entry), instead of the first control of the Form, and also you would call `myPanel.GetNextControl(...)` instead of `Me.GetNextControl(...)`. The other code lines should remain the same. If this is not helpful enough, add a comment and I will edit my answer.